# Como depurar solo una clase

Tags: android, android-studio

Muy buenas a tod@s. Resulta que quiero depurar solo la clase principal sin que el debugger vaya saltando a otras clases no escritas por mí.

Lo he intentado configurando el depurador segun el siguiente enlace pero no ha funcionado. Creo que es debido a que la respuesta es para una versión más antigua de Android Studio.

Debajo os dejo unas capturas de pantalla de como tengo actualmente configurado el depurador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tu comentario:

> Resulta que quiero depurar solo la clase principal sin que el debugger
>   vaya saltando a otras clases no escritas por mí.

puedes agregar las clases que no deseas depurar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dependiendo de tu proyecto tendrías que agregar todas las clases o paquetes que no deseas sean depurados.

Sin embargo lo más sencillo para evitar llenar de clases la configuración es:

**Depurar únicamente el programa, para esto usa la tecla: <kbd>F8</kbd> (Step over)**

> <kbd>F8</kbd> (Step Over) Ejecuta una línea de código. Si la
>   instrucción es una llamada a un método, ejecuta el método sin entrar
>   dentro del código del método.

ya que si usas <kbd>F7</kbd> para depurar (debugging - Step into), lo que estas realizando es depurar incluso los métodos de clases internas que usa tu código.

---

> El comportamiento que quisiera obtener es, una vez terminado el
>   analisis de mi codigo debe de detenerse la ejecucion del programa y
>   mostrar el valor de una variable que me gustaría analizar.

Para esto puedes usar el `LogCat`, el cual imprimiría el valor de la variable deseada en el LogCat, por ejemplo:

```
Log.d("MainActivity", "Valor variable: " + variable);
```

[Escribir y ver registros en LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html)

Otra forma de verificar el valor de varables, es realizar depuración mediante <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes verificar el valor de las variables agregando [breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#breakPoints) (puntos de interrupción), y mediante el puntero del mouse verificar el valor de las variables, aún sin terminar la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Jorgesys. Utilizo el F8 (Step Over). Una vez analizado el método que quiero ejecutar el depurador continua saltando a otras clases.


El comportamiento que quisiera obtener es, una vez terminado el analisis de mi codigo debe de detenerse la ejecucion del programa y mostrar el valor de una valiable que me gustaría analizar.


En la configuración del debugger todo lo posible a excluir está escluido.


¿Podría conseguir el conportamiento que estoy requiriendo?


Un saludo

Comment: @Purple_Bull agregué 2 opciones para esto, si deseas obtener el valor da la variable terminando la aplicación puedes usar el LogCat, en tiempo de ejecución puedes usar "puntos de interrupción".

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Jorgesys. 

Para terminar y hacer más concisa la duda que me queda, ¿cómo prodría hacer para que el depurador solo analizase la clase donde estoy escribiendo el codigo y no salte a ninguna otra nuca jamas?

Comment: @Purple_Bull estas corriendo la aplicación mediante "Run" o "Shift+f10" ? se supone que si lo realizas de esta forma solo ejecuta el programa pero no se detiene. En cuanto a que acceda aún realizando "Debug" o "Shift+f9" en este caso tendrías que agregar las clases en la opción "Do no step into the clases" pero no se me hace algo práctico agregar infinidad de clases que puede tener un programa! :|

Comment: ♦ Todo esto que te comento es en el debugger (Shift+F9).
Como se ve en las imagenes que adjunté arriba he añadido "android.*" al listado "do not step into the classes" con el objetivo de que no entre a verficar en ninguna otra clase mas que la que yo escribí. Aun así sigue entrando. No se porque :/